# Octopus deploy to create azure subscription's

Tags: azure, octopus

Octopus only allow to add Azure account (subscription level). Our requirement is to having create azure subscription using ARM template's and move to management group. Is there a way we can achieve the same .

Comment: You can refer this article to create subscriptions with arm templates(https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-governance-and-management/creating-subscriptions-with-arm-templates/ba-p/1839961)

Comment: As per the current [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=rest-getEnrollments%2Crest-EA%2Crest-getBillingAccounts%2Crest-getBillingProfiles%2Crest-MCA%2Crest-getBillingAccount-MPA%2Crest-getCustomers%2Crest-getIndirectResellers%2Crest-MPA) , Using various REST APIs you can create a subscription for the following Azure agreement types:
Enterprise Agreement (EA)
Microsoft Customer Agreement (MCA)
Microsoft Partner Agreement (MPA)